# Search npm security vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, security, npm, dependencies

I want to check vulnerabilities per package on the Internet.

There is this list: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories
But without search this list is useless. Can I somehow search it?

For example at this moment, at the top I see `preact` has high severity vulnerability. But if I open https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact there is no note here that the latest (or some version) of library has a security vulnerability.

Comment: Are you trying to check your the vulnerabilities for the node packages in your own project?

Comment: Well. I know there is npm audit for that. But I want to get it per package on the npm webpages. Perhaps this is not possible. I also opened a request on their issue tracker: https://npm.community/t/improve-security-vulnerabilities-interaction/7364

Comment: You can try out Snyk https://snyk.io/